# session issue with django+apache+mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, session, authentication, mod-wsgi

I've written a django application, and put it on a CentOS server. It is definitely okay when I use django development web server.

Such as I start it by "python ./manage.py runserver", and access that server from browser on another computer. I can sign in one time, and access all the pages without issues.

However when I run it with apache+mod_wsgi, I just found I have to login with user and password time by time. I think maybe there is some problem with the session middleware, so, how can I find the root cause and fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different options for this.

In order of likelyhood (imho):

- The session backend uses the cache system to store the sessions and you're using the `locmem` cache backend
- The session backend isn't storing the cookies (secure cookies enabled? cookie timeouts? incorrect date on the server?)
- The session middleware might not be loaded (custom settings for production server?)

Storing the session in the cache is only a good solution if you use memcached as the cache backend. So if you're storing the sessions in cache, make sure you use memcache :)

Either way, check if `SESSION_ENGINE` is set to `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db`

Comment: My settings of them are: `CACHE_BACKEND = 'file://%s' % os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'cache').replace('\\','/')`, and `SESSION_ENGINE = django.contrib.sessions.backends.db`. Does this cause problem? I've check the **cache** folder, there are no files. But I've already set it permission to 766, am I right?

Comment: I am now using daemon mode `WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=apache group=apache threads=25`.

Comment: @William: If your session engine is set to `...backends.db` than you're not using the cache backend to store the sessions. In that case I would guess it's some kind of a cookie problem. You can test it like this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies

Comment: it is okay now. very strange. I found previously, I've set `SESSING_ENGINE` to `cache_db`, maybe it cause error. Thanks a lot.