# About Django's way to prevent multiple logins same account

Tags: python, django, account

Is there any "official" Django way to prevent multiple Humans to login in the same account simultaneously, or do I have to do this system by my own?

I don't have any problem with more than one person using the same account. But I don't want them to use the same account simultaneously on different devices.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/821870/9225671

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8927327/9225671